# Facing the curtain (of the ICU)

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

### I realised that Health.SE is not much fun for me anymore.

Explaining why this is the case would take too long and feel somewhat like a rant, but this has been covered in multiple Meta threads and chats, if you are interested.

Furthermore, I don't give the current site a chance of survival.

A combination of these two factors has led to my decision to take a step back from the site.

### So I shall fall into a comatose state

<s>I would like to thank the Academy, my GP, my pharmacist, my professor and my parents</s> sorry, wrong speech, and yes, I've [copied that joke](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7917/80374).

The truth is, I had a slight overdose of pentobarbital and am in a medically induced coma. Okay, to be honest, a [convenient coma](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ConvenientComa) might be the better title.

It has been great fun here, and obviously I want to thank a few people for their support and encouragement (in no particular order):

- thanks to the users I have had more contact with through chat and Meta
- thanks to the users introducing me to the site and helping a newbie to SE
- thanks to the moderation team, who has a lot of work to do here and manages it
- thanks to those who helped me learn more about Health
- thanks to those who corrected my somewhat mediocre answers or encouraged me to update them, helping me learn in the process
- thanks to those taking care of this site and helping it grow
- thanks to those who have answered my questions
- thanks to those who have provided questions for my answers

Obviously, I have also had some trespasses:

- thanks to all the new users tolerating my frequent editing, and my apologies for changing posts too much
- thanks to all the users accepting my standard request-for-sources text and updating, and my apologies for being pedantic
- thanks to all the users who always questioned my theory of how the site works and remembered me of the Community wishes, and my apologies for ignoring the Community at times

### Coma is not death

That's important to note. When scheduling and planning for a induced coma, usually the patient is awakened a few days later.

I don’t think I‘ll return pretty soon, I have the site a few months and tried as much as I could, but nothing really changed. Feel free to notify me if any significant changes take place in the future.

[status-comatose](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-comatose)